# Order by related fields of different models in Django Admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

I want to order by the `business_name`, but the ordering isn't working due to some relationships, below is my first model :

```
class LoanApplication(models.Model):

    loan_id = models.CharField(
        'Loan Application ID', max_length=40, unique=True, null=True,
        blank=True)
    loan_taker = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomerProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name='Customer Profile', related_name='loan_entries')
    submitted_date = models.DateTimeField(
        'Submitted Date', null=True, blank=True)
```

then, I have the `CustomerProfile` model as below :

```
class CustomerProfile(models.Model):

    customer_id = models.CharField(
        'Customer Profile ID', max_length=64, unique=True, null=True)
    cooperation_partner = models.ForeignKey(
        EmailUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Jurisdiction'), related_name='partner_user_profile')
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        EmailUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('User'), related_name='user_profile')
    tipster_partner = models.ForeignKey(
        TipsterPartner, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name='Tipster Partner')
```

So, I wanted to point to the Business model , it's as below :

```
class Business(models.Model):


    business_id = models.CharField(
        'Business ID', max_length=64, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    business_name = models.CharField(_('Business'), max_length=128)
    business_address_street = models.CharField(
        'Business Address Street', max_length=50, blank=True)
```

then, we have the last one which is the CustomerProfileBusiness as below :

```
class CustomerProfileBusiness(models.Model):

    business = models.ForeignKey(
        Business, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Business'),
        related_name='customer_profile_relation')
    correlative_id = models.CharField(
        _('Business ID'), max_length=64, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    customer_profile = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomerProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name=_('Customer Profile'), blank=True, null=True,
        related_name='business')
```

Now, I do the ordering in the Admin page of the **LoanApplication** as below, **but it doesn't work**:

```
@admin.register(LoanApplication, site=admin_site)
class LoanApplicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = (
        '-modified',
        'loan_taker__business__customer_profile_relation__business_name',
    )
```

So my target is to sort the `business_name` in the **ascending** order but using a relationship approach in the Admin page of the **LoanApplication**

Comment: What does not work? Since you are first order on `'-modified'`, it means that you will only order on the `business_name` in case of a *tie*. But if `modified` is a `DateTimeField`, the odds of a tie are practically zero, since the two modifications can be off by a few nanoseconds.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thanks for your contribution, however my question is , is the relationship correct `loan_taker__business__customer_profile_relation__business_name` ?